# Application logs are not pushed to grafana loko

Tags: spring-boot, grafana-loki, observability

I am working on adding observability(using grafana stack) to my spring boot microservives.

I can't see logs in my grafana loki dashboard. I think issue is with some configuration in one of docker-compose, otel-collector.yml,
OpenTelemetryConfig file. links of code below

otel-collector.yml: https://github.com/raju4789/tourna-mate/blob/master/docker/collector/otel-collector.yml

docker-compose.yml : https://github.com/raju4789/tourna-mate/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

OpenTelemetryConfig: https://github.com/raju4789/tourna-mate/blob/master/tourni-identity-service/src/main/java/com/tournament/config/common/OpenTelemetryConfig.java

Full code here: https://github.com/raju4789/tourna-mate/tree/master

I was trying to follow this article to add observability: https://medium.com/@ahmadalammar/comprehensive-observability-in-spring-boot-using-opentelemetry-prometheus-grafana-tempo-and-e08842ae96be

Please help. I am struck on this for a while now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: Code is already provided above